# how can i get the value of selected radio button if i click the select button and pass its value in a textbox?

Tags: php, javascript

```
 //this is saved in president.php
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM candidate_info WHERE position= 'president'"))
                    {
     // display records if there are records to display
       if ($result->num_rows > 0)
                            {
          // display records in a table
           echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";

              // set table headers

          echo "<tr><th>Student ID</td><th>Course</th><th>Name</th><th></th></tr>";

  while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
             {
        // set up a row for each record
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->studid . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->course . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->fname . " ". $row->mname ." ". $row->lname ."</td>";
echo "<td><input type ='radio' name='radio'  value='". $row->studid ."'> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
                               }


  echo "<td> <input type='button' name='button' value='select' onclick='". get_radio_value() ."'></td>";

    echo "</table>";
     }

     else {
        echo "No results to display!";
                            }
      }
```

//this my javascript to read and get the value of my radio

```
   function get_radio_value()
      {
      for (var i=0; i < document.orderform.radio.length; i++)
        {
          if (document.orderform.radio[i].checked)
            {
             var rad_val = document.orderform.radio[i].value;
             }
        }
       }
```

//here i would show the value of my selected radio as i click the select button on the //textbox where inside my form
     " />

//but as i load my page, i got an error

```
// like this Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_radio_value()
```

//this is the code for my voting.php

```
      <div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
      <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">President</li>
      <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Secretary</li>
      </ul>
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
      <div class="TabbedPanelsContent"><p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p><?php require_once('candidate/president.php'); ?></p>
     <p>&nbsp;</p></div>

              <td width="292" valign="top">
    <form method="post" action="voting.php" >
         <table width="289" height="76" border="0" cellspacing="1">

          <tr>
            <td width="131" height="24" ><div align="right">President</div></td>
            <td width="151"><div align="left">
                <input type="text" name="president" id="radio_value"/>
            </div></td>
          </tr>


        </table>
   </form></td>
```

Answer (score 3):

change this

```
echo "<td> <input type='button' name='button' value='select' onclick='". get_radio_value() ."'></td>";
```

In this it is calling php's `get_radio_value()` function, but the function is written in javascript, so use below code.

```
echo "<td> <input type='button' name='button' value='select' onclick='get_radio_value()'></td>";
```

**for passing the value of radio button in textbox**

```
<input type="text" name="president" value="WHAT CODE SHOULD I PUT HERE?" id="radio_value"/>
```

change this line

```
var rad_val = document.orderform.radio[i].value;
```

to

```
return document.getElementById('radio_value').innerHTML = document.orderform.radio[i].value;
```

Comment: thanks Yogesh, but i still one more problem, how could i pass the value as i click the select button into my textbox? i have another html form where i want to print or echo the value i selected. 
ex. <td>President</td><input type="text" name="president" value="WHAT CODE SHOULD I PUT HERE?"/>

Comment: sir Yogesh, i still could not print the value on my textbox, the above codes i presented is saved as president.php, and the other html file which i want to print the value i selected as i click the button on textbox is save in voting.php.... i still got no response on my textbox, pls help me what should i do...